# ScrollView for all iPhones simulators

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

For some reason, I could not find a simple answer and know a couple people from my school who had trouble with this too. I have a `UIScrollView`, and want let users scroll through it like the way it runs in the simulator for iPhone 7, but when I run it on an iPhone SE, the scroll view is a much longer and the label previously viewable inside the view now is farther down in the view and you have to scroll farther down. Now I can tell you my steps, and then show you some pictures. So I put a scrollview in my view then I put a view on top of the scroll view, but scroll view and view were pinned 0 in all directions. But I set the view height to 700 and control clicked from the view to the parent view and said equal widths. Then set viewcontroller to free form and set the height to 700. Then I added a button and a label just pinned to top right and left for button on and bottom left and right for label (0 to the bottom). This question is to answer a beginners question on what code should he or she implement to have the scrollview resize to each size iPhone. Here's photo of the storyboard.

[image]

I do not have any code written in the viewcontroller except for 3 outlets - label, button, and scrollview.

Please tell me what code I need to implement to correct this issue, thank you.

Comment: I see constraints in your screenshot, yet I'm hearing nothing about them. About 8 months ago I released an app with a horizontal scroll view (still have that code archived) that worked in all devices. I replaced it with a segmented control, so it will take some time to help you. My problem? Your question doesn't show me you understand *either* auto layout *nor* UIScrollview. It really doesn't give me anything to guide you with. Don't leave it at "help me". Leave it with "this is what I've tried" and "this is exactly what I need".

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest you is, Instead of taking a `UIScrollView`. Take a `UITableViewController`, and make the `UITableView` as Static. Now take one cell and add the labels the way you want.

No need to create a Custom Table Cell class, you can directly drag and drop the outlets and action.

Please remove all the Datasource and delegate methods, except the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

And mention the row height as screen size. Now it will manage as per the device height. Will look approximately same in all the devices.

Thanks.

Feel free to ask if you didn't understand my answer.